# Customizing tmux status to represent current working directory and files

Tags: tmux

I've been playing with this for a couple of days, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Love tmux. Using it for development and have so many windows I need a better way of distinguishing them in the status bar and in the buffer list. Seeing a list of "bash" and "vim" isn't really helpful at all. And since they're all on the same host - don't care about the hostname right now.

I'd like to show the current working directory, and the file being worked on. For example when I view the list of buffers I currently see:

(0)    0: vim [100x44] (1 panes) "murph"
(1)    1: vim [100x44] (1 panes) "murph"
(2)    2: bash- [100x44] (1 panes) "murph"
(3)    3: bash* [100x44] (1 panes) "murph"

Here's what I'd like to see
0:vim main.py ~/devl/project1
1:vim index.html ~/devl/samples/staticfiles
2:bash           ~/devl/sandbox
3:bash           ~/.vimrc

I'd like to see similar info in the status bar for each individual window. While I am able to get PWD to show up in the status bar of a window, it's only the working directory from where tmux was launched. This isn't any help as I change directories.

I'm hoping this can be done without a bunch of scripts.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

For bash add to .bash_profile or whatever:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"\\033]0;\${USER}@${HOSTNAME}\\007\\033k\${PWD}\\033\\\\\""
```

For vim add to .vimrc:

```
if &term == "screen"
    set t_ts=^[k
    set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
    set title
endif

autocmd BufEnter * let &titlestring = "vim " . expand("%:t") . " " . expand("%:h")
```

For those not familiar, to get the escape sequence ^[ in vim, press Control-V Escape.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `~/.tmux.conf` to get have current directory (of the pane you are one) show in tmux status

```
set -g status-left-length 100
set -g status-left '#[fg=green] #T#[default]'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually affect the tmux status line

Comment: Thanks. This is what I come up with and prefer,
set -g status-right-length 100
set -g status-right '#T'

Comment: didn't work for me